# There is an issue with my jQuery on-click logic

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to change the value of `img` and `p` under the `assign-btn` section with the value of `img` and `p` respectively from the `employees` section. Here is what I have been able to achieve so far:

The Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = '';
  var name = '';
  var check = false;

  $(document).on('click', '.emp-row', function() {
    $(this).find('.employees').on('click', function() {
      img = $(this).find('.get-img').data('imgid');
      name = $(this).find('.get-name').data('name');
      check = true;
    });

    if (check) {
      $(this).find('.set-img').attr('src', img);
      $(this).find('.set-name').text(name);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row emp-row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="assign-va" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      <div class="assign-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-btn">
                    <div class='avatar-img-left'>
                        <img src='images/fe1.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg set-img'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='avatar-text-right' style="margin-top: 0">
                        <p class='avatar-name set-name' style="text-align: left">
                            John Doe
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="parent-employee">
        <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
          <div class='avatar-img-left'>
            <img src='images/fe2.png' data-imgid='images/fe2.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img'>
          </div>
          <div class='avatar-text-right'>
            <p class='avatar-name get-name' data-name='Jasmine Undoe'>
              Jasmine Undoe
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="empid" id="empid">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
          <div class='avatar-img-left'>
            <img src='images/fe3.png' data-imgid='images/fe3.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img'>
          </div>
          <div class='avatar-text-right'>
            <p class='avatar-name get-name' data-name='Jenne Redoe'>
              Jenna Redoe
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="empid" id="empid">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row emp-row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="assign-va" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      <div class="assign-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-btn">
                    <div class='avatar-img-left'>
                        <img src='images/fe1.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg set-img'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='avatar-text-right' style="margin-top: 0">
                        <p class='avatar-name set-name' style="text-align: left">
                            John Doe
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <div class="parent-employee">
        <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
          <div class='avatar-img-left'>
            <img src='images/fe2.png' data-imgid='images/fe2.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img'>
          </div>
          <div class='avatar-text-right'>
            <p class='avatar-name get-name' data-name='Jasmine Undoe'>
              Jasmine Undoe
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="empid" id="empid">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
          <div class='avatar-img-left'>
            <img src='images/fe3.png' data-imgid='images/fe3.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img'>
          </div>
          <div class='avatar-text-right'>
            <p class='avatar-name get-name' data-name='Jenne Redoe'>
              Jenna Redoe
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="">
            <input type="hidden" class="empid" id="empid">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I am changing the value on the first `emp-row` everything seems to be working however, the problem is, when I am trying to change the value on the second `emp-row` the value from the first row is getting assigned at first and then everything works normally as the way it should.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: The first time you click on a row all you do is add click handlers to the employees in that row. So you have to click on the employee again to run that click handler. It's almost always wrong to add one click handler inside another click handler. Just create all the employee click handlers outside the row click handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have more than a few challenges here.

- `button` element should only contain phrasing content so no `div` or `p`
  Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element SO I changed those.
- You don't need those global variables so I just moved them and use `let` to constrain scope instead.
- `id` attributes are unique identifiers so duplicates are not allowed Ref:https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute So I removed those.
- Use the recommended short form of `$(document).ready(function()` of `$(function() {`
- You are attempting to access the row element for some elements and the target element for others so I added the `event` and then accessed the  `let $parentRow = $(event.delegateTarget);` which is the element where the event handler is attached  `$('.emp-row')`
- never add a NEW event handler for a click inside another click event handler unless you remove it first - so I used the proper form with the delegate instead.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.emp-row').on('click', '.employees', function(event) {
    let $parentRow = $(event.delegateTarget);
    let img = $(event.delegateTarget).find('.get-img').data('imgid');
    let name = $(this).find('.get-name').data('name');
    console.log(img, name);
    let check = true;
    if (check) {
      let $sentname = $parentRow.find('.set-name');
      let imgel = $parentRow.find('.set-img');
      // console.log("If these are 0 they do not exist:",$sentname.length, imgel.length);
      $sentname.text(name);
      imgel.attr('src', img);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row emp-row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="assign-va" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <div class="assign-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-btn">
          <span class='avatar-img-left'>
            <img src='images/fe1.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg set-img' />
          </span>
          <span class='avatar-text-right' style="margin-top: 0">
              <p class='avatar-name set-name' style="text-align: left">
                  John Doe
              </p>
          </span>
</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="parent-employee">
          <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
            <div class='avatar-img-left'>
              <img src='images/fe2.png' data-imgid='images/fe2.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img'>
            </div>
            <div class='avatar-text-right'>
              <p class='avatar-name get-name' data-name='Jasmine Undoe'>
                Jasmine Undoe
              </p>
              <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="empid">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
            <div class='avatar-img-left'>
              <img src='images/fe3.png' data-imgid='images/fe3.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img'>
            </div>
            <div class='avatar-text-right'>
              <p class='avatar-name get-name' data-name='Jenne Redoe'>
                Jenna Redoe
              </p>
              <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="empid">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row emp-row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="assign-va" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        <div class="assign-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-btn">
          <span class='avatar-img-left'>
              <img src='images/fe1.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg set-img'>
          </span>
          <span class='avatar-text-right' style="margin-top: 0">
              <span class='avatar-name set-name' style="text-align: left">
                  John Doe
              </span>
          </span>
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="parent-employee">
          <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
            <div class='avatar-img-left'>
              <img src='images/fe2.png' data-imgid='images/fe2.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img'>
            </div>
            <div class='avatar-text-right'>
              <p class='avatar-name get-name' data-name='Jasmine Undoe'>
                Jasmine Undoe
              </p>
              <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="empid">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="employees" style="cursor: pointer">
            <div class='avatar-img-left'>
              <img src='images/fe3.png' data-imgid='images/fe3.png' class='me-2 rounded-circle avatar avatar-lg get-img'>
            </div>
            <div class='avatar-text-right'>
              <p class='avatar-name get-name' data-name='Jenne Redoe'>
                Jenna Redoe
              </p>
              <input type="hidden" name="mydata" class="mydata" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="empid">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I have one small comment to make:

I had to change this code:
`let img = $(event.delegateTarget).find('.get-img').data('imgid');`
to this code:
`let img = $(this).find('.get-img').data('imgid');`
and everything worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!!!